# How to put the names in the code from .txt document for it to read

Tags: python, linear-search

This code is trying to open a txt document read the names print them then ask to input a name and search for the name but the search doesn't work with text only with set names if anyone can help. I think its using data a a search request so don't know how to make the names it

```
def liner_search():
    with open ("example.txt", "r") as myfile:
        data = myfile.read().splitlines()
        print (data)
        numberList = [data]
        searchRequest = input("enter name:")
        print(searchRequest)
        found = False
        i=0
        while found == False and i != len(numberList):
            if numberList[i] == searchRequest:
                print ("found")
                found = True
            else:
                print("next")
            i = i+1

liner_search()
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BycE.png)

Comment: Example code should usually include example data so that we can run and edit the code to answer the question.  Here, you should put `namelist = ['Reece', ...]` at the top of the code.  Output text should be included in the question instead of pasting an image of the output elsewhere (where it will eventually disappear).  Your question 'how to make the names it' is incomplete or unclear.

Comment: data is already a list. You shouldn’t wrap it in another list.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a more pythonic approach:

```py
def name_finder():
    with open('example.txt', 'r') as my_file:
        data = my_file.read().splitlines()
        name = input("enter name:")
        if name in data:
            print("Name is in the list")
        else:
            print("Name is not in the list")

name_finder()
```